# How to obtain cumulative distribution function for a specific probability density function via R

Tags: r, distributions, mathematical-statistics, beta-distribution

I have the following probability density function.

$$f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{B(a,b,c)}\dfrac{x^{(a-1)}y^{(b-1)}(1-x)^{(b+c-1)}(1-y)^{(a+c-1)}}{(1-xy)^{(a+b+c)}}$$

I wrote the following `r code` to obtain the probability density function in `r`

```
alpha <- c(6,20,2)
Consbeta <- function(a) {
  exp(lgamma(sum(a))-sum(lgamma(a)))
}

mypdf <- function(x, y, alpha){
  numerator <- x^(alpha[1]-1)*(1-x)^(alpha[1]+alpha[2]-1)*y^(alpha[2]-1)*(1-y)^(alpha[1]+alpha[3]-1)
  denomenator <- (1-x*y)^(sum(alpha))
  pdf <- numerator/(denomenator*Consbeta(alpha))
  return(pdf)
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to obtain cumulative distribution function for the above pdf via `r`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Consider numeric integration.  *Mathematica* is able to integrate once and obtains an expression involving the Appell 2D hypergeometric function, but is unable to do the second integration.  Although that doesn't mean a closed form expression is not available, it's usually a strong indication of it.

Comment: @score324 I have same problem, that I have to calculate cdf of a function. But I no idea about Mathematica (as suggested by @whuber). Can you please the share that solution you used for above mentioned question?